# Can't get Denim on Lumia 1520

Tags: lumia-denim-update, nokia-lumia-1520

I got a Lumia 1520 from Hong Kong. However, I live in Hungary (maybe that's the problem?)
I should be able to update my phone to Denim, but it doesn't give me the option to update my phone.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't give you the option to update your phone"? As in it checks for updates, but finds nothing?

Comment: It says my phone is up to date but I should be able to see the denim update according to the MS availablity page

Answer (score 1):

Please note that I'm posting this answer assuming that your ambiguous statement "*it doesn't give me the option to update*" means that you go to Settings->Phone Update and every time you check it tells you that your phone is up to date.

First go to [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/support/software-update/wp8-software-update/) website and see if the update is available for your phone country variant. If it's not, the only things you can do are: wait or flash your phone with different (country variant) firmware. If it is available, read the rest of my answer.

No, the fact where you live or what regional settings you have set should not matter.

If you have enabled the "Preview for Developers" then this is your problem. I've read somewhere that when you enable the PfD program, your phone looks for updates on different servers which do not have the Denim update. You have to go to the "Preview for Developers" app and disable it (you can re-enable it after the update). Then of course go to Settings->Phone Update and use the "Check for updates" button. This has solved my problem.

If both you don't have the PfD and the the website says the update is available for your phone, possibly the only other things you can try are to:

1. Restore the phone to factory settings (Settings->About and click "Reset your phone" - obvoiusly this will remove everything from the phone).

or if that doesn't work:

2. Use the official Windows Phone [Software Recovery Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987) and reinstall your OS (this will also remove everything from your phone).

If this doesn't work I don't know what else will.

Comment: First of all ofc  it says my phone is up to date so I cant update it.
The phone should be available to update denim as the microsoft availablity says (its available for Hong KOng users)
I was not in the PfD (now I joind in, try if it works but still no update for me) and I have tried restoring it with the recovery tool.
How can I update/change my firmware manually? :O

Comment: I most certainly didn't have to disable PFD.

Comment: @Shawn There must be some other dependence. I absolutely had to switch it off temporarily (and it's not just me) and it worked right away.

Comment: @PappDániel I can't really walk you through the process of flashing the phone manually but when I did this with my Lumia 920 over a year ago I had find the firmware and download it and then flash it with software called "Nokia Care Suite". There are some tutorials on the web that make it easy. Usually when you find a website with a firmware to download there are some instructions on how to flash it as well. Fortunately Lumia phones are not as easy to brick as some other brands.